# Overly long user location entry breaks mobile users view

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, users-page

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1078583/zx81) as a humorous long location set:

> Under your desk. Really. I'll give you thirty points if you look there and confirm that you saw me.

This breaks the mobile view of the Users page; the location field pushes the second column all the way over to the right:

[image: mobile Users page broken]
[image: mobile Users page broken]

This is not limited to the left column, nor to just Stack Overflow. The following is from Super User, where [this user](https://superuser.com/users/36565/hello71) makes sure that we know where they are located in the event of cross-multiverse first contact:

[image: mobile Users page broken]

Comment: Working fine in the mobile theme viewed on a computer so it's only matter of screen size. Still a bug of course!

Comment: The mobile web view of the users list has changed and this is no longer an issue. Voting to close it.

Answer (score 2):

The easy CSS fix for this is:

```css
table.grid-tag { table-layout: fixed }
```

This causes the columns to be always shown at their intended width, regardless of how much text some users might cram into them.

**Ps.** This fix is now included in [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.16.  While the practical benefit of having this fix in SOUP is somewhat limited by the fact that few if any mobile browsers support user scripts, it's simple and obvious enough that I felt its inclusion was "morally justified" anyway.